# Is there a way to execute all the 3 queries together?

Tags: neo4j

```
    MATCH (b:brand {brandname:'AUX'})<-[r1]-(s:product {`name`:'aircondiner'}) RETURN s.id, s.name limit 10

    MATCH (s:product {`name`:'refrigerator'}) RETURN s.id, s.name limit 10

 MATCH (b:shop {shop_name:'xyz'})<-[r1]-(s:product {`name`:'refrigerator'}) RETURN s.id, s.name limit 10
```

I need to speed up the graph query process. Currently, my program executes these 3 queries one by one. Is there a way to merge these queries together and execute at one time, which may potentially speed up a lot?

Comment: What about UNION?

Comment: 1) Your query is not parametrized, 2) have you created some indexes ? 3) the output of each query are the same so you can use a UNION like stdob said